# Parallelize without input variables

Tags: python, parallel-processing

With what functions can I parallelize without input only with the function? Can you give me an example of code?

```
def calculate():
  ...
  return result

pool = mp.Pool() 
p=pool.starmap(calculate)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Usually `pool.starmap` is used to call a function with many different inputs in parallel. Do you want to run the `calculate` function multiple times in parallel or are you expecting some magic to parallelize your single function call for you?

Comment: The quick-hack would be to pass some dummy input data.
Why do you need this? You might be better of with some other approach to parallelism.